# Checking baggage to a non-destination airport

Tags: luggage

Flying from SLC to Warsaw with a 6hr layover in Amsterdam. I will be returning to Amsterdam two weeks later to join a river cruise. Can I claim luggage in Amsterdam from the first leg of the flight, store it at baggage storage and retrieve it when I return to join the river cruise?

Comment: Which airline? I presume KLM or Delta?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. This is called *short-checking*. You must request it at the check-in counter but it is at the discretion of the agent that serves. Usually, they are reluctant to do this for a short connection but 6H is plenty. You may have to explain yourself to convince them but if you have the confirmation from the cruise I would expect it to be considered a good reason.

Comment: As this is also what you would do if you planned on not using the ticket for the second leg (there are several questions here describing how tickets get cheaper when adding a leg), I wouldn't be surprised if the OP also have to document some kind of plans in Poland.